# Two Row Table With Three Columns Using Divs

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-float

I've looked at other questions and none of them answer what I'm looking for here.  The requirements I need:

Three columns
Two rows
Header row
All text align toward the top

Code I currently have:

```
<style type="text/css">
.major {
    width:700px;
    height:350px;
    float:left;
}
.one {
    width:220px;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
    top:0px;
}
.two {
    width:220px;
    height:300px;
    margin-left: 240px; 
    top:0px;
}
.three {
    width:220px;
    height:300px;
    margin-left: 480px;
    top:0px;
}
#head {
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="major"> 
    <div class="one">
    <p id="head">Head One</p>
    <p>This is text within the body under the head and next to other text that looks like a table.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
    <p id="head">Head Two</p>
    <p>This is text within the body under the head and next to other text that looks like a table.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
    <p id="head">Head three</p>
    <p>This is text within the body under the head and next to other text that looks like a table.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But how this looks is nothing like a table.  One, the text is not aligned toward the top, like a table.  Second, the third box is actually further down, almost like it's a completely other line.

In looking through some other questions, I did try a few other techniques like playing with the top, align-top, etc, but none of them yielded success for aligning with the top.  I also tried removing the p tags in thinking that they may be confusing the interpreter about where the boxes should be; no success.  The current look of this - which is incorrect is something like:

> Text 1|Text 2
>
> Blank|Text 3

It should look like:

> Text 1|Text 2|Text 3

Comment: well you want a table but you didn't specify that in your code. the code can't guess what you want. use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` . see my answer below

Comment: Just correcting the HTML and removing the extra `</div>` seems to fix this - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/pbQxwG Votng to close as a **typo**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want it to 'look' like a table use `display:table` on `.major` and on all the `divs` inside use `display:table-cell` and remove the `floats` and the `widths`

also your HTML was incorrect. you had a `</div>` closed wrong

see snippet below :

let me know if it helps.

```css
.major {
    width:700px;
    height:350px;
    display:table;
}
   

#head {
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;

}
.major div { 
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:center;
    height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="major"> 
    <div class="one">
    <p id="head">Head One</p>
    <p>This is text within the body under the head and next to other text that looks like a table.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
    <p id="head">Head Two</p>
    <p>This is text within the body under the head and next to other text that looks like a table.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
    <p id="head">Head three</p>
    <p>This is text within the body under the head and next to other text that looks like a table.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually didn't understand what you require as you are using divs and not table.

I have made the divs behave like tables using `display: table` below. Is the below what you are expecting?

```css
.major {
  display: table;
}
.one {
  display: table-cell;
}
.two {
  display: table-cell;
}
.three {
  display: table-cell;
}
#head {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="major">
    <div class="one">
      <p id="head">Head One</p>
      <p>This is text within the body under the head and next to other text that looks like a table.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <p id="head">Head Two</p>
      <p>This is text within the body under the head and next to other text that looks like a table.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="three">
      <p id="head">Head three</p>
      <p>This is text within the body under the head and next to other text that looks like a table.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#tabel1 td{padding:10%; 0%}
tr td:first-child{text-align:right}
tr td:last-child {text-align:left}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id="tabel1" style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>Lastname</td>
                    <td><select><option>select</option></select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jackson</td>
                    <td><select><option>select</option></select></td>
                </tr>
            </table> 
        </td>

        <td>
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>Lastname</td>
                    <td><textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Smith</td>
                    <td><textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jackson</td>
                    <td><textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
            </table> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```